# How to redirect after successful Async call with react-router?

Tags: javascript, react-router

I am using the react-router to navigate through my react/flux application.

> **Where I still have problems is:** How is the best way to redirect to a new page (or just change the URI params) after a successful API
>   call?

I have a API.js, where my async-calls are (with superagent). The actual call is done in my app-actions.js:

```
createWorkspace( workspace ) {
    Api.createWorkspace( workspace )
      .then(function( workspace ) {
        dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.CREATE_WORKSPACE, workspace });
        history.replaceState('/workspace/' + workspace.body.data._id);
      }, function(error) {
        dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.FAILED_TO_CREATE, error });
      });
  }
```

I am dispatching the success or failure event. So everything is according to the flux pattern.

As you can see, I am using `history.replaceState` to change the URL. But it is replacing all of the things, including the Hash.

To be honest, it's a nightmare. I am finding ES5 with react 0.13 things, I find ES6 with react-router 0.14 and ES6 with react-router 1.0 solutions.

I even don't remember where I found this `history.replace` method.

#### What I am using

- React 0.14
- react-router 1.0
- ES6 syntax

Can somebody please tell me where my problem is? Why is the most straight forward ToDo, redirecting, such a huge deal? **Should I just use plain JavaScript here and manipulate the browser url by my own?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure it out what the best practice could be. So here is how I've done it.

Create a **history.js** file

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

And then, the not so nice solution, I have to replace the whole URL, so I have to take care of the hash sign while creating the new one:

```
history.replaceState(null, '#/workspace/' + workspace.body.data._id);
```

So here is my AppActions.js:

```
import AppConstants from '../constants/app-constants';
import { dispatch, register } from '../dispatchers/app-dispatcher';
import Api from '../lib/api';
import history from '../lib/history'

export default {
  addRestaurant ( restaurant ) {
    dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.ADD_RESTAURANT, restaurant });
  },
  removeRestaurant ( restaurant ) {
    dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.REMOVE_RESTAURANT, restaurant });
  },
  createWorkspace( workspace ) {
    Api.createWorkspace( workspace )
      .then(function( workspace ) {
        dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.CREATE_WORKSPACE, workspace });
        history.replaceState(null, '#/workspace/' + workspace.body.data._id);
      }, function(error) {
        dispatch({ actionType: AppConstants.FAILED_TO_CREATE, error });
      });
  }
}
```

[Working solution is here.](https://github.com/gruberb/CompanyLunch)